# Makefile plugins for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I am working on a project that requires me to understand building of complex makefiles. Is there any eclipse plugin that can help me do that?

I just want to understand what a function does/ variables values and it would be great if it could give me a flow chart for the same.

Comment: To be clear: are you asking about plugins for managing complex makefiles or a tutorial?

Comment: For managing complex makefiles, but either would help. :)

Comment: I don't have any experience in this area but a cursory search seems to indicate that Eclipse natively supports makefiles. Consider clarifying your answer to specify what kind of plugin you're looking for or what you're trying to do that the normal editor doesn't cover.

Comment: I just want to understand what a function does/ variables value and it would be great if it could give me a flow chart for the same.

Comment: If you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30649315/edit) that info into your answer it will pop back up in the message queue and I imagine you're more likely to get an answer.